# calculate Check Number in Java

Tags: java

Not sure if anyone can explain this to me or help me.

I have a 15 Digit Number of which I want to multiply each even number by 2 unless the even number is greater than 9. If it is this needs to be subtracted by 9 to give me an integer that again I can multiply by 2. Once I have all the even numbers multiplied by 2 i need to add them all together with the odd numbers.

Does that make sense.

UPDATE ***
so i have a number say 49209999856459. for that number I am looking to get the even integer so for example the first even one would be 4 then the second would be 2 and so on.

If one of those even numbers are multiplied by 2 then it might be above 9 so I want to subtract 9 to then use the remainder as the even number in its place.

SO !!!
Multiply by 2 the value of each even digit starting from index 0 and then each even index. In each case, if the resulting value is greater than 9, subtract 9 from it (which reduces larger values to a single digit). Leave the values of the digits at the odd indexes unchanged.

```
public String calculateCheckNumber()

  String firstFifteen = longNumber.substring(0,15) ;
  int i, checkSum = 0, totalSum = 0;
  for (i = 0; i<firstFifteen.length(); i += 2) {


while (i < 9)
        i *= 2;
 if   (i > 9)
       i -= 9 ;
       
}
```

Was one option I was trying but it honestly I cant seem to get my head around it.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In the while loop, it's only going to stop if i is 9, so... what? And I suppose that you mean the digits(in the while loop), right? Not the entire number.

Comment: What do you mean by even number?  Divisible by two on in an even position (ie. the 2nd, 4th, 6th digit).  Also, a 15 digit number.  How can a digit be > 9.  Please explain with an example?  Also include the expected checksum.

Comment: Does each even number mean each digit in the 15 digit number that is even? What is the scenario when it will be greater than 9?

Comment: so i have a number say 49209999856459. for that number I am looking to get the even integer so for example the first even one would be 4 then the second would be 2 and so on.

If one of those even numbers are multiplied by 2 then it might be above 9 so I want to subtract 9 to then use the remainder as the even number in its place.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is one approach.  This uses the ternary (?:) operator to condense the operations.  Edited base on clarification from the OP.  The example you gave is actually a 14 digit string.  But the following will work with any number of digits if they start out in a string.  If you have a long value, then you can create the character array using:

```
long v = 49209999856459L;
char[] d = Long.toString(v).toCharArray();
```

Here is the main algorithm.

```
String s = "49209999856459";
int sum = 0;
char[] d = s.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    int v = d[i] - '0';
    // The even digit will only be greater than 9 after
    // doubling if it is >= 5 before.
    sum += ((i % 2) == 1) ? v : (v >= 5) ? v+v-9 : v+v; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Prints

```
86
```

Comment: I like this approach.

Comment: thanks for that kinda of helps. although I think I have confused you a bit. I was looking for it to take ever second character in the string and double that. Thats what I meant by even. Even on the string not the individual character. So if the number was 4895523 the Numbers i would want to be doubled would be the 4,9,5,3.If that makes sense ?

Comment: Multiply by 2 the value of each even digit starting from index 0 and then each even index. In each case, if the resulting value is greater than 9, subtract 9 from it (which reduces larger values to a single digit). Leave the values of the digits at the odd indexes unchanged.

Comment: @EirmisSolutions Since you are new to SO I think you should know that it is highly frowned upon by the moderators to re-post the same question.  You could get banned for repeated infractions. The proper procedure is to edit the first one with any updates.  In any event I modified my answer based on your clarification.  Please take a look.